# is it possible to declare a large array as static and use it as extern in other files in c

Tags: c, arrays, static, extern

i have a very big array which is shared among many functions in many files in a vc project. My  problem is, I have to declare it in **main()** and use **extern** in the header files. Since the array is too large for the stack i have to use static which makes it impossible to have the extern declaration in the header files.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:

What i did was as you said but i get **error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol**

Here is my global declaration and the extern declaration:

**main.c**

static unsigned char          bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS];

**hdr.h**

extern  unsigned char          bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS];

**ROWS** and **COLUMNS** could grow as large as 1024 and 1048576 respectively

Comment: I doubt "too large for the heap". Anyway, alloc/initialize the data at program start (static or whatever works) and set up an "extern" pointer provide access to said data. Might also want to look at `mmap` to keep the data separate...

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @pst: dont you think 24MB of space is "too large"?

Comment: @John - no. I'd imagine pretty much any machine you're using Visual Studio to compiler for can allocate 24 MB without too much effort.

Comment: Wait - are you mixing up "heap" and "stack"?

Comment: @CarlNorum: yes i did mix it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By making it `static`, you're avoiding overflowing the stack (the heap isn't involved), but by placing it inside `main` no other parts of your program can access it directly.

To share between functions and files in the same program, you must define it outside of main, and put an `extern` declaration for it in a header that you'll include in the other files that need to access it:

big_array.c:

```
#include "big_array.h"

int my_big_array[big_size];
```

in big_array.h:

```
 #define big_size 1234567

 extern int my_big_array[];
```

Then any other file that needs access to it just:

```
#include "big_array.h"

// ...
my_big_array[1234] = new_value;
```

Comment: i just have done like this except that i have put the array size in the extern declaration.

Comment: @John: That doesn't hurt anything, but the size in the declaration is ignored. I did just edit -- you normally want to define the size in the header.

Comment: @John: Looking at your edited question, however, there is one thing you really need to change: remove the `static` from the definition. The static keeps that definition from being visible in other translation units, even with an extern declaration.

Answer (score 6):

Declare a global pointer and share it among all of your source files (via `extern` in a header).  Then populate that global pointer in `main()`.

Edit:

Your comments on your question seem to indicate that you're confusing the heap with the stack.  Just make your array global and share access to it with an `extern` declaration in a header.  Problem solved, and no funny tricks to be pulled.